# Cropping Image is not cropping correctly

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drawing

I have followed a YouTube Tutorial on how to create a cropping image application.

**Goal:**

My Goal is simply load a screenshot image into `PictureBox1`.

Then mark an area with a Red Rectangle to crop and display into `PictureBox2`.

**Here is the code:**

```cs
public partial class Form18 : Form
{
    Rectangle Rect;

    Point LocationXY;
    Point LocationX1Y1;

    bool IsMouseDown = false;




    public Form18()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void Form18_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Clipboard image
        pictureBox1.Image = Clipboard.GetImage();
    }


    private void picturebox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        IsMouseDown = true;
        LocationXY = e.Location;
    }

    private void picturebox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsMouseDown == true)
        {
            LocationX1Y1 = e.Location;

            Refresh();
        }
    }

    private void picturebox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsMouseDown == true)
        {
            LocationX1Y1 = e.Location;

            IsMouseDown = false;

            if (Rect != null)
            {
                Bitmap bit = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);

                Bitmap cropImg = new Bitmap(Rect.Width, Rect.Height);

                Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(cropImg);
                g.DrawImage(bit, 0, 0, Rect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                pictureBox2.Image = cropImg;
            }
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Rect != null)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, GetRect());
        }
    }
    private Rectangle GetRect()
    {
        Rect = new Rectangle();

        Rect.X = Math.Min(LocationXY.X, LocationX1Y1.X);

        Rect.Y = Math.Min(LocationXY.Y, LocationX1Y1.Y);

        Rect.Width = Math.Abs(LocationXY.X - LocationX1Y1.X);

        Rect.Height = Math.Abs(LocationXY.Y - LocationX1Y1.Y);

        return Rect;
    }

}
```

**Output:**

And here is the output output:

On the left hand side - you can see the screenshot input and on the right hand side - you can see the cropped image.

I do not understand - the rectangle marked in Red does not crop the image correctly? - it shows different area of the screenshot image.

Where is the going wrong?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I have tried the code and it is working fine. Did you miss any code in the post?

Comment: No, definitely did not miss anything. That's strange - Could it be because of dual screen monitor?

Comment: I have tried with extended monitor and its working. What is the sizemode for the picturebox?

Comment: @AjithNair all normal - what is yours?

Comment: Try with StretchImage. I have included in the answer below.

Comment: @AjithNair the quality is horrible - but I see what is going on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of *flooding* the memory with disposable `Graphics` and `Bitmap` objects in the `MouseUp` event of the `PictureBox1`, handle the `Paint` event of `PictureBox2` and use the supported `Graphics` object to draw, and just use the `e.Graphics.DrawImage` overload to pass the source and destination rectangles.

```cs
//...
private Point LocationXY;
private Point LocationX1Y1;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Clipboard.ContainsImage())
    {
        pictureBox1.Image?.Dispose();
        pictureBox1.Image = Clipboard.GetImage();
    }
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        LocationXY = e.Location;
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        LocationX1Y1 = e.Location;
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        LocationX1Y1 = e.Location;

        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        pictureBox2.Invalidate();
    }
}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (MouseButtons == MouseButtons.Left)
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, GetRect());
}

private void pictureBox2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var src = GetRect();

    if (src == Rectangle.Empty) return;

    var des = new Rectangle(0, 0, src.Width, src.Height);

    e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
    e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;

    e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureBox1.Image,
        des, src, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}

private Rectangle GetRect()
{
    return new Rectangle(
        Math.Min(LocationXY.X, LocationX1Y1.X),
        Math.Min(LocationXY.Y, LocationX1Y1.Y),
        Math.Abs(LocationXY.X - LocationX1Y1.X),
        Math.Abs(LocationXY.Y - LocationX1Y1.Y)
        );
}
//...
```

Use the following to get the cropped image:

```cs
//...
private Bitmap GetCroppedImage()
{
    var src = GetRect();

    if (src == Rectangle.Empty) return null;

    var des = new Rectangle(0, 0, src.Width, src.Height);
    var b = new Bitmap(src.Width, src.Height);

    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(b))
    {
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;

        g.DrawImage(pictureBox1.Image, des, src, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }
    return b;
}
//...
```

Then you can save it like:

```cs
private void Save()
{
    using (var d = new SaveFileDialog())
    {
        d.Filter = "PNG|*.png|JPEG|*.jpeg;*.jpg|BMP|*.bmp";

        if (d.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) return;

        using (var b = GetCroppedImage())
        {
            if (b == null) return;

            ImageFormat f;

            switch (d.FilterIndex)
            {
                case 2:
                    f = ImageFormat.Jpeg;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    f = ImageFormat.Bmp;
                    break;
                default:
                    f = ImageFormat.Png;
                    break;
            }

            b.Save(d.FileName, f);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: SOQ60819266]

Comment: What variable would I then use to save it as .JPG?

Comment: @LV98 You got me. I'll add a method for that

Comment: the image also stretches sometimes - how can this be avoided?

Comment: I'll take a look now

Comment: Hey man, do you know how I can resize the new image in `pictureBox2` with current code by `* 0.8`? I am not sure where to look.

Comment: @LV98 Hey buddy! Welcome back. You need to ask a new question in this regard. Better to get many answers instead of one. Right? :)

Comment: Thanks man! - You provided me with a great answer and your attitude towards is great, thought I'd ask you again aha! Can I use your code to put in the new question?

Comment: @LV98 Of course buddy. Once it posted and accepted, it became your code. You own it now. :)

Comment: I have just posted the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

Setting the SizeMode to Normal may not crop the image with the following code

```
Bitmap bit = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
Bitmap cropImg = new Bitmap(Rect.Width, Rect.Height);
```

The cropping will be relative to the Picturebox width and height.

Change the new Bitmap line to the following

```
Bitmap bit = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image, pictureBox1.Image.Width, pictureBox1.Image.Height);
Bitmap cropImg = new Bitmap(Rect.Width, Rect.Height);
```

OR Set the SizeMode of the picturebox to StretchImage

```
this.pictureBox1.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
```